# Python import from module fails when using unittest

Tags: python, import, python-unittest

I have a module foo that imports bar, that works calling and importing from main.py as

```
main.py   -> import module
module:
   __init__.py
   foo.py   -> from module.bar import *
   bar.py
   test_foo.py
```

but now I want to unit test it and added a test importing foo which cannot find bar and it seems adding

```
import sys; sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
```

"fixes" this. How can I check in "foo" that it is imported from test_foo and not main? Or is there some better way to structure this (searching for Python imports seem to result in a never ending rabbit hole of methods)?

Comment: Could you add the failing `import` code from test_foo.py?

Comment: If you are using the unittest package from the standard library, start the tests with `python -m unittest` from the main directory. Use `--help` for details.

Comment: @KlausD. I tried the -m flag but that didn't help

Comment: @JanWilamowski I just have an 'import foo' statement

Comment: "that didn't help" is not a great error description. In fact you did not even post the command line and output of the original call. If you want to get good help, give good debugging information!

Comment: when running `python -m unittest discover` from the project root, you might have to import your modules using `from module import foo`